# Passing arraylist in function and changing its reference, does not work outside the function

Tags: java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CheckClass {
    static ArrayList<String> curr2=new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
    ArrayList<String> curr=new ArrayList<>();
    System.out.println(curr);
    CheckArr(curr);
    System.out.println(curr);
    }
    private static void CheckArr(ArrayList<String> curr) {
        curr2.add("hi");
        curr=curr2;
        System.out.println(curr);
    }
}
```

Its output is :

```
[]
[hi]
[]
```

Can anyone explain how i can change the reference of curr to curr2.
I just switched from C++ to java. I think it has something to do with internal pointer mechanism of java, can you explain this concept.

Comment: Java is not like c where you can change the pointer to a new memory address. The closes think to that is if the curr2 would be a field member class.

Comment: @dreamcrash Yeah that solved my question. but Is there no way in java by which above thing will be possible ?

Comment: No, Java is pass-by-value, you can't just change the paradigm of a programming language when it seems convenient.  You can either return the reference, and assign it to `curr`, or you can expand the scope of `curr` to outside the method.

Comment: I mean, if you pass an array of objects, then you can change the object in one of the array positions. But doing like you did there is no way around it

Answer (score 0):

In Java when you pass any Object to a function, the reference to this Object is passed by value. That's why, when you change the reference to the Object, it will change only in function.